# How to serialize objects in java? rewrite graphhopper.mapmatching into spark

Tags: apache-spark, kryo, graphhopper, map-matching

I am trying to rewritten the map matching algorithm [graphhopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching) into spark. I want to broadcast the 'map infomation' to each worker and distribute the traces to each worker.
However, the class `MapMatching` (which stores the map infomation) is not is not `Serializable`. I have tried using `kryo` to serialize it but it does not work.

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error constructing instance of class: > com.graphhopper.matching.MapMatchin

Can I instantiate the `MapMatching` after broadcasting? Or how can I make it serializable? Or are there any solutions?

Comment: I think you could try to create your own class, inherit from MapMatching and implement the Serializable interface. If using Kryo, did you try write your own custom serializer?